# Geometric view point of this question

Tags: linear-algebra

$T$ be a linear transformation on $V$, we need to show

1) ${\rm Image} (T) \subseteq \ker (I-T) $

2) $\ker (T) \subseteq {\rm Image} (I-T) $

I need to know what is the geometry behind this question,

Algebraic solution is easy by noticing $x= Tx+(I-T) x$

Comment: What is $A$ in your question?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: You must have other hypotheses, Belle Noiseuse.  Without ant hypothesis it's false. Probably $T $ is a projector.

Comment: Shouldn't you be given that $T^2=T$?